# how do i run a bat file as if it's interactive?

Tags: file, batch-file, input, cmd

I have an issue where if i run a command manually it prompts for the next volume. which is fine, i can use the '< inputfile.txt' to run this through a batch file.

But what happens if the volume in inputfile.txt hasn't yet been created? - I get an error and the programs crashes out.

I cant change the program that prompts unfortunately as its bundled in a .exe.

My theory would be to run the program as if it's interactive with no '< inputfile.txt' and make the calling program wait until the volume is complete before providing the next volume.

i'm running this:

```
create.bat  < cInputFile >> cTempLog
```

and get

> ** Cannot find or open file

if i run manually i get:

> Please enter next device or file name or type 'quit' to exit:

Any help would be great,
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could write a second batch file to pipe the input into `create.bat` and sleep before each line.

something like this i'd guess:

```
@echo off
for /f "delims=" %%i in (cInputFile) do sleep 1 && echo %%i
```

and run it something like:

```
input.bat | create.bat >> cLogFile
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I'll give this a try and let you know.

Comment: This seems to do the trick, i need a bit more intelligence around the sleep command (which i changed to 'timeout \t') in order to check a file exists, but the general idea works very well.